# How to add dynamic UI to fragment tabs?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I have used a FragmentTabHost to create four tabs with corresponding fragments. The tabs work, however, now that I want to add dynamic UI (such as a TextView that displays the current date, and interactive buttons) I am not sure how to proceed. I have found that trying to add it to the fragments is incorrect and adding it to the main also causes error. There must be some way to do this, but my lack of android experience has me lost. So, is there a way to add dynamic UI to fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have created FragmentTabHost like in in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html).

You have now to define each fragment which will be in each tab. For example, in the doc, there are 4 fragments referenced :

```
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
            LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);
```

- FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment
- LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment
- LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment
- LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment

Those are only examples of Fragment implementation (you can found their implementation in the doc).

Then, it depends what you'd like to have in each tab (display a list, a few buttons,..).
You can have a look at the training lesson [Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) or the documentation about [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: +1 thanks for the reply. And yes, I am using a FragmentTabHost from the documentation. I looked at your links, however I am still lost. I have added a button to the xml layout, but when I go to the fragment to try and make that button interactive, it crashes. Essentially the button appears, but when I try to add my code, it stops working because I am not putting it in the right place (i think). I have also tried adding it to the TabActivity and MainActivity to no avail.

Comment: Here is the exact code I am attempting to add:                  `final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton0);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked", 5).show();
 }
});`

Comment: Have you implemented your fragment and inflated your layout (xml) in the onCreateView method ? If not, you should do it, like explained in the documentation guide : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html